# Python ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded even though the JSON is valid

Tags: python, json

I have a valid JSON file (verified with [this](https://jsonlint.com/) website) that all of sudden can't be read.

This script has been working since forever. I'm not sure what changed.

This is the script:

```py
import os
import json

basepath = '/path/'
for entry in os.listdir(basepath):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basepath, entry)):
        with open("{}/{}".format(basepath, entry), 'r') as myfile:
            data=myfile.read()

        obj = json.loads(data)
        if obj.get('enabled'):
            print("test")
```

This is the full error:

```
File "src/utils/process_utils.py", line 34, in invoke
    raise ExecutionException(result_code, error, output)
utils.process_utils.ExecutionException: Execution failed. Code 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conf/scripts/script.py", line 12, in <module>
    obj = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I use `read()` and `loads` to make sure everything is a string. Looking for ideas on what could have changed, because this script has been working since forever and it's automated.

Edit:

Just tried without `read()`. Just `json.load` and it gives the same output.

Edit2:

An example for the JSON file:

```json
{
    "id": 1234567,
    "login": "jsmith",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "first_name": "John",
     ...
     ...
}
```

The rest of the file just looks the same, more parameters about users.

`find . -not -name "*.json"` didn't find non-JSON files.

printing the `data` variable:

```
John Smith (jsmith)
{
    "department_number": 123,
    "department_name": "Department",
    "anpa_dep": "Dep",
    "requester": nul
}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conf/scripts/script-server_anpa_users.py", line 13, in <module>
    obj = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

the `"requester": nul` looks weird. Gonna try to remove that specific json.

Comment: can you show an example of your json file?

Comment: before `obj = json.loads(data)` do `print(data)` . share the output please.

Comment: Any reason for using python 2.7?

Comment: This code will try load the contents of all/any files in the basepath. Perhaps they're not all JSON files

Comment: Have you tried using `data=myfile.readlines()` before the `json.loads()`?

Comment: Just because a file has a .json extension doesn't mean that its contents are valid JSON. Wrap the loads() function call in try/except then print the rogue filename when the exception occurs. Then you can inspect that file's contents using other tools

Comment: @balderman One sufficient reason: According to the question, it is legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from the comments that only files with a .json suffix are to be considered. On that basis I propose this more robust approach:-

```
import glob
import json
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    base = '/path'
    for entry in glob.glob(os.path.join(base, '*.json')):
        with open(entry) as infile:
            try:
                _json = json.load(infile)
                if _json.get('enabled'):
                    print('test')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Failed to load {entry} -> {e}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a rouge .json file that wasn't parsing correctly. I printed the `data` variable and saw that some json file was getting stuck. Weird...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
import os
import json

basepath = '/path/'
for entry in os.listdir(basepath):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basepath, entry)):
        with open("{}/{}".format(basepath, entry), 'r') as myfile:
            data=myfile.read()
        print(data)
        try:
            obj = json.loads(data)
        except ValueError:
            # this will point to the problematic file
            file_name = "{}/{}".format(basepath, entry)
            print('file {} is not a valid json'.format(file))  
        if obj.get('enabled'):
            print("test")
```

Comment: The most likely exception to be raised is json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Comment: JSONDecodeError appears to be sub-classed from ValueError. However, that's not documented and could therefore change in a future release of Python